# Source and destination servers showing different number of established TCP connections

Tags: centos, postgresql, tcp, jboss, netstat

I have a JBoss app server and a Postgres database server on different machines. I'm troubleshooting TCP connections between them (because the app keeps running out of database connections).

I'm seeing this and it makes no sense:

- When I do a netstat on the database server, I see lots of established TCP connections from my app server.
- When I do a netstat on the app server, I see almost no established TCP connections to the database server.

The machines are VMware virtual machines running Centos, managed by a cloud provider (not AWS). There's no firewall between the machines (as per [Too many established connections left open](https://serverfault.com/questions/504187/too-many-established-connections-left-open)) which does seem like similar behaviour.

I don't know what else could cause this asymmetry?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange. Seems like a the app server just doesn't receives `FIN`s and someone else answering them, it may be a problem on your cloud provider. However, you still can try a workaround for this problem and close old connections once in a while. See [Is there a timeout for idle PostgreSQL connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236160/is-there-a-timeout-for-idle-postgresql-connections) for more informations about how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for this, that does look like a good workaround. After further investigation, it's looking like this is indeed a problem at the cloud provider end. The probable cause is a firewall-type issue related to their VMware configuration, which fits with the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else seeing this behaviour, it was confirmed as a problem with the VMware setup at the cloud provider end, as suggested @Shmuel Hazan.

If I've understood correctly, this was a problem with the VShield edge, which is why the observed behaviour matched that of a firewall cutting off the connection.

Once the provider rectified the fault, normal service was restored.